# How to limit the height of a ListView within a GridLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

I have a `GridLayout` containing a `ListView` and a `TextView`. When items are added
to the `ListView` it will grow in size and push the `TextView` below it out of the
screen. I thought that by setting `layout_gravity="fill"` on the ListView it
would not grow at all but rather take up all the available space.

How do I configure the `ListView` to take up the available space instead of
growing and pushing views below it out of the screen?

I am looking for a solution using a `GridLayout`. I am aware that in my case a
`LinearLayout` would work aswell. However this is just a minimal test case to
illustrate my problem.

I do not want to set the height programmatically, if possible.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:columnCount="1"
    app:useDefaultMargins="true" >

    <ListView
        app:layout_gravity="fill" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView" />

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Comment: Just so I understand your question, you want your ListView to be a static height and individually scrollable? As in, when you scroll within the ListView, the rest of the GridView will not scroll.

Comment: Yes, the ListView should take all the available space. It should also be scrollable, but the GridView should not scroll and the TextView below the ListView should always be visible.

Comment: You can't do what you want simply by using a GridLayout directly. Even the documentation states that the widget doesn't support the concept of weight and suggests wrapping the children in a LinearLayout.

Comment: From [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout.html): _"GridLayout does not provide support for the principle of weight. In general, it is not therefore possible to configure it to distribute excess space between multiple components.
Some common use-cases may nevertheless be accommodated as follows. To place equal amounts of space around a component in a cell group; use CENTER alignment (or gravity). For complete control over excess space distribution in a row or column; use a LinearLayout subview to hold the components in the associated cell group..."_

Comment: So, since the _`ListView's`_ height isn't fixed and expands with a new content you cannot achieve the desired behavior via xml attributes unless you use a _`LinearLayout`_ with weight or _`RelativeLayout`_ as a wrapper for the _`ListView`_ and _`TextView`_.

Comment: @Onik The documentation talks about distributing excess space between multiple components. I do not have multiple components to take excess space, but only a single component - the ListView.

Comment: i wonder why u are using `GridLayout` although it contains only `ListView` and `TextView`. If u don't want to scroll to show `TextView`, just use `RelativeLayout`. Use correct layout class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer extends my comments to the question and attempts to explain *`why this cannot be done with XML via GridLayout's attributes`*.

Adding *`GridLayout`* to the framework allowed solving a range of drawbacks regarding nested layouts, one of wich was *`"inability to control alignment along both horizontal and vertical axes simultaneously"`* as described in the article [New Layout Widgets: Space and GridLayout](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html) by Philip Milne.

This alignment control is performed by *`layout_gravity`* parameter whose [*`description`*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity) states that the parameter *`"specifies how a component should be placed`* ***`in its group of cells",`*** (***`NOT within a root layout`***). Basically, it's the same as that of *`LinearLayout`*, which also mentioned in the article: *`"Alignment/gravity also works just like gravity in LinearLayout..."`* And as we know, for *`LinearLayouts`*, once a view has taken the whole height of the screen (like *`ListView`* in your case), the views below it go behind the screen if the layout oriention was set to *`"vertical"`*.

If we look at the [GridLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout.LayoutParams.html) documentation we won't find any parameter which would allow a component within a cell group to stick to a certain position of the parent layout and stay at the position independent of the size of other components within the same group; similar to the [*`layout_align[...]`*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) parameters of a RelativeLayout.

My best guess about the absence of this kind of parameters in *`GridLayout`* is better alignment control compare to nested layouts.

I'm sure you know a solution(s) for your problem using an approach other than *`GridLayout's`* attributes. I'll just suggest one to make the answer look accomplished:

```
<GridLayout
    ... >

    <RelativeLayout
       ... >

        <TextView
            ...
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

        <ListView
            ...
            android:layout_above="@id/tv">
         </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically set the height of the ListView as follows:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) listView.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.height = listHeight;
listView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

However, I can't think of a way to make this scale well for multiple devices.

Answer (score 0):

Only way you can limit size of ListView with wrap content as height, is extending class, overriding onMeasure method and setting your limit for height there. I am not aware of any xml params whích would give you desired effect.

Comment: Where/how is ListView set to "wrap_content"?

Comment: well you are right that it is not defined with GridLayout children, but from your description it looks like it behaves as it was (I havent tried myself). But my suggestion is still valid. GridView will send  you into onMeasure method size of available space. If you use this values with setMeasuredDimensions. You should be restricted on available space.

Comment: It is like Onik said in his comment, but if you want to avoid wrapper layouts you can use my suggestion. Do you understand in principle or should I provide you with some code?

Comment: I am looking for an XML solution or an explanation why this cannot be done with XML alone.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can set your TextView inside a footer, and then the ListView will not push it. Altough I'm not sure if that is what you want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <!-- TextView Here -->

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Content below header and above footer -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/footer"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <!-- ListView Here -->

</RelativeLayout>
</GridLayout>
```