# Why doesn't match_parent work when view is larger than viewport?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-gridlayout

UPDATE - 9/28/2015:
I have reached the desired appearance by replacing my oriented `GridLayout`s with `TableLayout`s that use `TableRow`s for horizontal siblings with a `layout_weight=1` and a `layout_weight=1` also on any cell item that is the lowest vertically-aligned sibling.

I am building a UI that is made up of a nested grid of many unequal rows and columns.  The lowest level views inside the grid must fill the remainder of the screen.  The views are all dynamically inflated except for the `ScrollView` and frame.

I am using `GridLayout`s that are set to `match_parent` for both width and height.  The child views (the views that actually go inside the cells of the grid) are also configured the same way.  Each cell contains a vertical `LinearLayout` with the first view being the title bar of the lane and the second view being another `GridLayout`.

For some reason when my grids become large enough to go off screen because of the amount of items, I notice that other nearby views lose their ability to fill the screen.

CORRECT EXAMPLE (notice right purple square fills space)
[image: correct]

INCORRECT (as soon as views go outside screen, making `ScrollView` take effect, right purple square doesn't match parent)
[image]

I'm guessing it has something to do with the views losing ability to determine height once the `ScrollView` kicks in.

A better way to demonstrate it is by putting this layout XML in Android Studio and removing the `LinearLayout` with ID = **REMOVE_ME_NEXUS_S**.
and then adding it back again using a small screen preview device like Nexus S.  When you remove the `LinearLayout`, the right side view fills the screen but when you put it back it only goes as big as its `minHeight`.

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/board_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        tools:context=".BoardActivity">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/lane_margin"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                >

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lane_title_frame"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lane_tv_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/lane_title_text_size"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/lane_title_margin"
                        android:textColor="@color/lane_title_text_color"
                        tools:text="@string/dt_lane_title"/>

                </FrameLayout>



                <GridLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout

                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/lane_margin"
                        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                        >

                        <FrameLayout

                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            >

                            <TextView

                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/lane_title_text_size"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:layout_margin="@dimen/lane_title_margin"
                                android:textColor="@color/lane_title_text_color"
                                tools:text="@string/dt_lane_title"/>

                        </FrameLayout>


                        <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:minHeight="@dimen/lane_minHeight"
                            android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
                            >

                        </GridLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/REMOVE_ME_NEXUS_S"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/lane_margin"
                        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                        >

                        <FrameLayout

                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            >

                            <TextView

                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/lane_title_text_size"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:layout_margin="@dimen/lane_title_margin"
                                android:textColor="@color/lane_title_text_color"
                                tools:text="@string/dt_lane_title"/>

                        </FrameLayout>

                        <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:minHeight="@dimen/lane_minHeight"
                            android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
                            >

                        </GridLayout>


                    </LinearLayout>


                    <LinearLayout

                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/lane_margin"
                        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                        >

                        <FrameLayout

                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            >

                            <TextView

                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/lane_title_text_size"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:layout_margin="@dimen/lane_title_margin"
                                android:textColor="@color/lane_title_text_color"
                                tools:text="@string/dt_lane_title"/>

                        </FrameLayout>

                        <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:minHeight="@dimen/lane_minHeight"
                            android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
                            >

                        </GridLayout>


                    </LinearLayout>



                    </GridLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout

                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/lane_margin"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                >

                <FrameLayout

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >

                    <TextView

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/lane_title_text_size"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/lane_title_margin"
                        android:textColor="@color/lane_title_text_color"
                        tools:text="@string/dt_lane_title"/>

                </FrameLayout>

                <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:minHeight="@dimen/lane_minHeight"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
                    >

                </GridLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </GridLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I do notice if I set `layout_rowWeight` to 1 on the right side `LinearLayout` that it will fill the parent, but it doesn't actually do it on my device, just in the studio preview window.

Comment: Try to enable "Show layout bounds" in the developer options. Enable it and post a new screenshot showing the bounds. If the developer button is not in the settings screen, then find the build number in the settings and click it several times until the developer options is enabled.

Comment: @CurlyCorvus, alright, I'll do that.

Comment: @CurlyCorvus all set.

Comment: May be [How to limit the height of a ListView within a GridLayout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26263183/how-to-limit-the-height-of-a-listview-within-a-gridlayout) would clarify some aspects of `GridLayout`?

Comment: @Onik, that helped me understand things a little, but not enough to get me to a solution.  Thanks though.

Comment: @some_developer you're welcome...It was right to add the layout xml to the question...

Comment: @Onik, I bet you are on the right track though, that it is some property of the GridLayout causing it.  I changed my layout to a TableLayout and it seems to work now...

Comment: @some_developer So, problem solved for you?

Comment: Yeah, it is solved by using something else.  Do you know how I should properly close the question? Just post an answer and mark it as accepted? @Onik

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90785/discussion-between-onik-and-some-developer).